# How to iterate through DOM elements changing id with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have 36 divs with ids id="square-1", "square-2", etc., framed in a grid 6x6 container. I want them to be all square and be the size of each square of the grid.
I want to make a function to add css to each of them to determine their position in the grid. In my mind I can do something to iterate through them with a for loop and apply "gridColumn = "a/b"", where a and b are relative to the i in the for loop, so that I don't have to specify that 36 times in the css document.
Is this even possible? Does it make sense? Very beginner...

```
    <div class="div-container">
        <div id= "square-1"></div>
        <div id= "square-2"></div>
        <div id= "square-3"></div>
        <div id= "square-4"></div>
        <div id= "square-5"></div>
        <div id= "square-6"></div>
        <div id= "square-7"></div>
         etc...
    </div>
```

Comment: This part isn't clear: _"I want to make a function to add css to each of them to determine their position in the grid"_. Can you explain in more detail what you want that function to do? Does it add more information to the divs? What kind of CSS are you currently using to display the divs in a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of elements by a CSS property is fragile. If you are using JavaScript, then let it do the heavy lifting. For instance, instead of hard coding 36 `<div>` with ids, make a `<div>` on each iteration of a loop. In the example below, the container is a `<main>` and each sub-box is a `<section>`. Each `<section>` is given a CSS property of `order` and a corresponding number and an id: "sq"+ a corresponding number. The `order` property applies to the order in which a flex item appears within a flex container.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('main');

for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
  const sec = document.createElement('section');
  sec.style.order = i;
  sec.id = `sq${i}`;
  box.append(sec);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 5vmin/1 Consolas
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid red
}

section {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  outline: 1px dashed blue
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: this one worked perfectly, and keeps the code super concise, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the parent element and loop through the child elements:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
var children = element.children;

for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
  var child = children[i];
  //apply changes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to iterate thru DOM elements you can do it by iterating thru every child that's div inside .div-container:

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.div-container div')
for(let square of squares){
   square.classList.add('YOUR_CLASS')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can use a css grid here.

To use this, you simply need to add css to the parent item (here your `div-container`) and populate with child elements which will be arranged in grid.

If you're beginner in HTML and css, you can generate grid using websites like [cssgrid-generator](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/).

---

### Small example

Small example here using a 2*2 grid

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  width: 210px
}

.child {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

Note : You can also generate the child elements using a for loop in javascript which will make your code lighter

Answer (score 0):

If you use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) use a loop to create the markup (I've used template strings pushed into an array) and add that (joined array) as the `innerHTML` of a container. You can add the array index as the data id attribute, along with a row/column attribute if you want to pinpoint the box's position in the grid.

In this example I've added a function that changes the box background color (an `,active` class) when it's clicked on.

```js
function makeGrid(n) {
  
  const boxes = [];
  let row = 0;
  let column = 1;
  
  for (let i = 1; i < n * n; i++) {
    
    column++;
    
    if (i % 6 === 1) {
      row++;
      column = 1;
    }
    
    const div = `
      <div
        class="box"
        data-id="${i}"
        data-row="${row}"
        data-column="${column}"
      >${i}
    </div>`;

    boxes.push(div);
  
  }
  
  return boxes.join('');

}

const main = document.querySelector('main');
main.innerHTML = makeGrid(6);

main.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.box')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
main { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 30px); gap: 0.5em; }
.box { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #676767; }
.box:not(.active):hover { background-color: lightblue; cursor: pointer; }
.active { background-color: salmon };
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Additional documentation

- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)